# How to get data from postgresql json array field

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have table field jsonb type and having below data.

```
{"roles": ["7", "73", "163"]}
```

I have to check "73" is present into or not by postgresql.

I have already search but the only gives solution for object of object not object of array.

I have tried below query but it does not work

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE field->'roles' ? ARRAY ['73'];
```

--updated--

also I need only that record which have exact value

{"roles": ["7"]}

{"roles": ["7", "73", "163"]}

i.e. field only have "7" not anything else in it.

Comment: Why do you use `ARRAY['73']`? Your query works fine with just `WHERE field -> 'roles' ? '73'`.

Comment: @Marth: Thanks I have search over half day for solutions on internet and stack overflow but you give it in a minute.

Comment: @Marth: Also I need to match exact array of that. May be that's why I am using ARRAY['73'] but it does not works :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE for all your cases:

**Does –single– key exists in json array:**

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    table 
WHERE   field -> 'roles' ? '73';
```

**Does -any- of the keys at right exists in json array:**

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    table 
WHERE   field -> 'roles' ?| ARRAY[ '7', '163' ] ;
```

**Does -all- of the keys at right exists in left json array:**

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    table 
WHERE   field -> 'roles' ?& ARRAY[ '7', '163' ] ;
```

**Does left json array match -exactly- with the right json array:**

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    table 
WHERE   field -> 'roles' = $$[ "7" ]$$::jsonb ;
```

Hopefully helps :)

Comment: Thanks It helps me a lot. :)